# CouchDB 2.1.1: Internal Server Error

Tags: couchdb, internal-server-error, couchapp, couchdb-2.0, fauxton

Before installing the [CouchApp](https://github.com/couchapp/couchapp) utility, [the Sofa blog app and the sample DB myblogdb](https://github.com/jchris/sofa) together with [CouchDB 2.1.1](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2.1.html) my CouchDB was working find and I never seeing any `Internal Server Error`.

In the last 2 hours a trojan attached itself as a process to the CouchDB. Since then I removed it, but it might have jammed some of the CouchDB's settings.

Why can't I run `myblogdb`? Does this error have something to do with the breaking changes caused by upgrade to `CouchDB 2.1.1`?

Firstly, `couchapp push` myblogdb only works on second attempt (first attempt ends in `Internal Server Error`):

```
$ couchapp push . http://admin:password@www.example.com:5984/myblogdb 
2018-02-09 16:53:09 [CRITICAL] {"error":"error","reason":"internal_server_error"}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Couchapp-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/couchapp/dispatch.py", line 45, in dispatch
    return _dispatch(args)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Couchapp-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/couchapp/dispatch.py", line 92, in _dispatch
    return fun(conf, conf.app_dir, *args, **opts)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Couchapp-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/couchapp/commands.py", line 72, in push
    dbs = conf.get_dbs(dest)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Couchapp-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/couchapp/config.py", line 159, in get_dbs
    return [Database(dburl, use_proxy=use_proxy) for dburl in dburls]
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Couchapp-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/couchapp/client.py", line 229, in __init__
    self.res.put()
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/restkit-4.2.2-py2.7.egg/restkit/resource.py", line 153, in put
    headers=headers, params_dict=params_dict, **params)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Couchapp-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/couchapp/client.py", line 144, in request
    raise RequestFailed(str(e))
RequestFailed: {"error":"error","reason":"internal_server_error"}
$ couchapp push . http://admin:password@www.example.com:5984/myblogdb 
2018-02-09 16:53:29 [INFO] Visit your CouchApp here:
http://www.example.com:5984/myblogdb/_design/sofa/_list/index/recent-posts?descending=true&limit=10
```

Secondly, running the `myblogdb` couchapp from the web browser:

[image: Internal Server Error in the browser]

`couchdb.log`:

```
[info] 2018-02-09T14:58:13.538108Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1196.0> -------- Opening index for db: shards/00000000-1fffffff/myblogdb.1518183029 idx: _design
/sofa sig: "0076c771c527a85eec3100fde6e69853"
[info] 2018-02-09T14:58:13.538160Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1197.0> -------- Opening index for db: shards/20000000-3fffffff/myblogdb.1518183029 idx: _design
/sofa sig: "0076c771c527a85eec3100fde6e69853"
[info] 2018-02-09T14:58:13.538194Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1198.0> -------- Opening index for db: shards/40000000-5fffffff/myblogdb.1518183029 idx: _design
/sofa sig: "0076c771c527a85eec3100fde6e69853"
[info] 2018-02-09T14:58:13.538241Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1199.0> -------- Opening index for db: shards/60000000-7fffffff/myblogdb.1518183029 idx: _design
/sofa sig: "0076c771c527a85eec3100fde6e69853"
[info] 2018-02-09T14:58:13.538294Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1200.0> -------- Opening index for db: shards/80000000-9fffffff/myblogdb.1518183029 idx: _design
/sofa sig: "0076c771c527a85eec3100fde6e69853"
[info] 2018-02-09T14:58:13.538347Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1201.0> -------- Opening index for db: shards/a0000000-bfffffff/myblogdb.1518183029 idx: _design
/sofa sig: "0076c771c527a85eec3100fde6e69853"
[info] 2018-02-09T14:58:13.538398Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1202.0> -------- Opening index for db: shards/c0000000-dfffffff/myblogdb.1518183029 idx: _design
/sofa sig: "0076c771c527a85eec3100fde6e69853"
[info] 2018-02-09T14:58:13.538516Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1204.0> -------- Opening index for db: shards/e0000000-ffffffff/myblogdb.1518183029 idx: _design
/sofa sig: "0076c771c527a85eec3100fde6e69853"
[notice] 2018-02-09T14:58:13.553289Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1144.0> 4852bad0c5 www.example.com:5984 24.134.87.25 undefined GET /myblogdb/_design/sofa/
_list/index/recent-posts?descending=true&limit=10 200 ok 83
[notice] 2018-02-09T14:58:13.633626Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1144.0> c80a6bd94f www.example.com:5984 24.134.87.25 undefined GET /myblogdb/_design/sofa/
style/screen.css 304 ok 2
[notice] 2018-02-09T14:58:13.680109Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1145.0> 3c55f8327b www.example.com:5984 24.134.87.25 undefined GET /_utils/script/json2.js
 404 ok 4
[notice] 2018-02-09T14:58:13.680338Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1146.0> 40f287a33e www.example.com:5984 24.134.87.25 undefined GET /_utils/script/jquery.j
s 404 ok 3
[notice] 2018-02-09T14:58:13.688782Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1144.0> f5f10f59e3 www.example.com:5984 24.134.87.25 undefined GET /myblogdb/_design/sofa/
vendor/couchapp/jquery.couch.app.util.js 304 ok 2
[notice] 2018-02-09T14:58:13.693473Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1147.0> 75b14f5d9c www.example.com:5984 24.134.87.25 undefined GET /_utils/script/jquery.c
ouch.js 404 ok 0
[notice] 2018-02-09T14:58:13.708853Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1148.0> 38ec74b4cc www.example.com:5984 24.134.87.25 undefined GET /_utils/script/sha1.js
404 ok 0
[notice] 2018-02-09T14:58:13.721734Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1149.0> 2171a940fb www.example.com:5984 24.134.87.25 undefined GET /myblogdb/_design/sofa/
vendor/couchapp/jquery.couch.app.js 304 ok 2
[notice] 2018-02-09T14:58:13.727197Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1144.0> 43ab936b5a www.example.com:5984 24.134.87.25 undefined GET /myblogdb/_design/sofa/
vendor/couchapp/jquery.mustache.js 304 ok 2
[notice] 2018-02-09T14:58:13.738777Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1145.0> 74a548f8bf www.example.com:5984 24.134.87.25 undefined GET /myblogdb/_design/sofa/
vendor/couchapp/jquery.evently.js 304 ok 2
[notice] 2018-02-09T14:58:13.745487Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1146.0> b9bc18f69a www.example.com:5984 24.134.87.25 undefined GET /myblogdb/_design/sofa/
script/app.js 304 ok 2
[notice] 2018-02-09T14:58:13.750103Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1147.0> 79cd8480f0 www.example.com:5984 24.134.87.25 undefined GET /myblogdb/_design/sofa/
script/md5.js 304 ok 2
```

Thirdly, I also receive `Internal Server Error` in Fauxton UI when creating/deleting any databases, but the request still gets executed:

[image: Internal Server Error when creating/deleting databases]

Comment: Is your CouchDB install a single-node or a multi-node cluster config?

Comment: It's single node.

Comment: Please, coul you check membership and update your post with the result? http://<your-couchdb-host>:5984/_membership

Comment: It gives me `{"all_nodes":["couchdb@localhost"],"cluster_nodes":["couchdb@127.0.0.1","couchdb@localhost"]}`

Comment: Then my answer was in the correct line. You should try to remove the wrong node from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are facing an issue in database creation/deletion due to a lack of cluster quorum: [Issue 603](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/603) and [Issue 1136](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/1136).

Probably your migration from 2.0 to 2.1.1 has some effect in the membership of your node and now you have to nodes registered one for couchdb@localhost and another one for couchdb@127.0.0.1

Couchdb is considering your instalation as a two-node cluster and you are facing the lack of quorum issues.

You can check it by using this URL http://<your-couchdb-host>:5984/_membership

It is possible to remove the wrong node in your config by follwing [these](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/cluster/nodes.html#removing-a-node) instructions.

Comment: Okay, the problem is solved, also had to move the shards to the new node `http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/cluster/sharding.html#cluster-sharding-move`